# Unable to convert .pem to .der

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, pem, der

I am trying to convert .pem file to .der which was given to me using OpenSSL but not successful. .pem file is password protected. File contains both certificate and private key

Command used

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der
```

I get this error

```
unable to load certificate
540409864:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
540409864:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=X509
540409864:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:crypto/pem/pem_oth.c:33:
```

Please advice how I can resolve this, thanks

Comment: Your file is damaged or wrong in some very strange way. I would 'give' it back. Failing that, I would extract the base64 body of the certificate block, decode, and look at a hex dump to see if it looks like ASN.1 or what else it does look like. If ASN.1 I would run it into `openssl asn1parse -i` to see if it looks like a cert with some damage I maybe might be able to fix sometimes or error(s) the issuer could fix, or something entirely different and if so what, and go from there. Also this isn't really a programming or development Q; I would try security.SX instead.

Comment: Thanks very much, the certificate wasn't valid. Requested the client to provide a certificate in the format required and that worked.